# Symbol for set all partitions of a set

Tags: notation

Is there a symbol for set all partitions of a set (like P for Power set)?

P.S. I need such symbol in writing some mathematical related notes.

Comment: You can use any symbol to represent that, as long as you define it so people know what it means. I'm not sure if there is a commonly used one.

Comment: Did you ever settle on a good notation for this?

Answer (score 3):

See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344464/notation-for-the-set-of-all-injections-from-a-into-b/344590#344590) to a similar question on MO. I suggest stealing notation from combinatorics and letting $\mathrm{B}_S$ denote the set of partitions of $S$, since the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $\mathrm{B}_{|S|}$ is the number of partitions of $S$.

Answer (score -2):

This is the commonly used symbol for the set of all subset of the set $E\:$ : $\mathscr{P}(E)$.

Comment: But that was not what was asked about.

Comment: Thanks hachem, but I need the symbol for the set all partitions of a set.

Comment: can you explain the meaning of the "set all partitions of a set" ?

Comment: wiki definition of partition of a set: "a partition of a set is a grouping of the set's elements into non-empty subsets, in such a way that every element is included in one and only one of the subsets." The set of all partition is a set which contain all partition of a set, e.g., for set A={1,2,3}, the set of all partitions would be B={ { {1}, {2}, {3} }, { {1, 2}, {3} }, { {1, 3}, {2} }, { {1}, {2, 3} }, { {1, 2, 3} }}.